# Error when trying to play audio file from URI

Tags: java, android, audio

So I'm completely new to Android programming and I'm starting off by trying to make an app that allows users to edit audio files. Here is my code so far, which makes a user upload an audio file and play it:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    final int ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE = 1;
    public String filePath;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.uploadbutton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent chooseFile;
                Intent intent;
                chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                chooseFile.setType("audio/mpeg");
                intent = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Choose a file");
                startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE);
            }
        });

        Button playButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.playbutton);
        playButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                                try {
                                    mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(filePath));
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                try {
                                    mp.prepare();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                mp.start();
                            }
                        });

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE: {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    filePath = uri.getPath();
                    getFilePath(filePath);
                    TextView URI_Text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.file_URI);
                    URI_Text.setText(filePath);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public String getFilePath (String filePath) {
        return filePath;
    }

}
```

However, I'm getting the error code `E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab756e00`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is not related to any of your code from your question. However, you are going wrong in other places.

`getPath()` is useless. The `Uri` should be treated as an opaque handle. Calling `getPath()` on a `Uri`, and expecting a file to be at that path, is akin to expecting there to be a `/questions/33843271/error-when-trying-to-play-audio-file-from-uri` path on your computer's hard drive, just because your browser happens to be showing a URL with that path.

Also, your access to the data represented by that `Uri` is short-lived. This is reminiscent of Web development, where you might be able to stream data from some URL for a while, but eventually your session times out. Saving the `Uri` is pointless. Either consume the data now (via a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()`), or don't bother with the data at all.

Comment: Thank you. I suppose I have to do some more research on the terms you have mentioned as they are foreign to me, but this is definitely a step in the right direction. Thanks again!